# Insert widget is not working on content page

Tags: magento-1.7, widgets

I am new to Magento. I am trying to add new **widget** on **content** page, So i followed the path

**CMS-->PAGES-->HOME-->CONTENT**

In this, I clicked on  "**Insert Widget**", But i shows empty window as shown in the image.

[image]

I also cleared "Cache", But could not find the issue. Please assist me for a solution.

Many Thanks

Comment: If your screen is blank there is probably an error in the ajax call that is supposed to fetch the widget types. Use firebug to see the result of all the ajax calls performed when adding a widget.

Comment: i can't get any response using firebug it shows empty response

Comment: Check your var/log folder for details. Also change in index.php the display_errors setting so in case there is problem you will see it.

Comment: did you fix this? my guess would be there is a problem with your widget.xml, if you have not fixed it could you post for xml

Comment: Empty widget screen happens without any error when widget is disabled inside System settings. Make sure it is enabled.